# How to Send Email When Computer is Locked?

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, scheduled-tasks

I want to send Outlook emails using Excel VBA.

The code `Sendupdate` works when run manually.

My second macro `StartTimer` is intended to execute the above at a set time when I am not at my desk.

When the computer is locked the email does not send. When I come back to my desk the email is hanging there as a draft, and I need to click the `send` button.

```vb
Sub SendUpdate()
    Recipient = "x@y.com"
    Subj = "update"
    Dim msg As String
    msg = "hello”
     
    HLink = "mailto:" & Recipient & "?"
    HLink = HLink & "subject=" & Subj & "&"
    HLink = HLink & "body=" & msg
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink (HLink)
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        Application.SendKeys "%s"
    End Sub
     
    Sub StartTimer()
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("18:00:00"), "SendUpdate"
     
End Sub
```

Is there a way to make sure the email gets pushed?

Comment: For these kind of operations, I never use Excel. I use the Windows Task Scheduler and a vbscript file to send the email from excel. If you are interested then I can show you an example. And definitely not `Application.SendKeys "%s"` as it won't work when your system is locked.

Comment: Hi Siddharth, thanks for your feedback.  if you don't mind, I would like to see an example of how you do that.  thanks a lot!

Comment: ok i need atleast 30 mins to write it, test it and then upload it here with screenshots :)

Comment: Could you confirm your windows operating system?

Comment: Windows XP.  Its my work computer (so has the usual logins etc).

Comment: I needed that info for snapshots for the task scheduler ;) The post is almost ready. I just tested it and it works fine :)

Comment: feel free to answer below for me to accept as well

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I will break this "Tutorial" in 3 steps

1) Writing your Excel Macro

2) Preparing your vbscript file

3) Setting the task in Windows Task Scheduler

---

**WRITING THE EXCEL MACRO**

---

Open a new File in Excel and in the module, paste this code

```
Option Explicit

Const strTo As String = "abc@abc.com"
Const strCC As String = "def@abc.com"  '<~~ change "def@abc.com" to "" if you do not want to CC
Const strBCC As String = "ghi@abc.com" '<~~ change "ghi@abc.com" to "" if you do not want to BCC

Sub Sample()
    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String, strSubject As String

    strSubject = "Hello World"
    strbody = "This is the message for the body"

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = strTo
        .CC = strCC
        .BCC = strBCC
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .Body = strbody
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Save the Excel File as `C:\Tester.Xlsm` if you are using Excel 2007 onwards or `C:\Tester.Xls` if you are using Excel 2003 and exit

---

**PREPARING THE VBSCRIPT FILE**

---

Open Notepad and then paste this code. Change the extension ".xls" as applicable.

```
Dim xlApp
Dim xlBook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Tester.xls", 0, True)
xlApp.Run "Sample"
xlBook.Close
xlApp.Quit

Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
```

Save the File as `Tester.vbs` and close it

[image]

---

**SETTING UP THE TASK IN WINDOWS TASK SCHEDULER**

---

> > > Could you confirm your windows operating system? – Siddharth Rout 36 mins ago
> > >
> > > Windows XP. Its my work computer (so has the usual logins etc). – keynesiancross 18 mins ago

Click on the Start Button | All Programs | Accessories | System Tools | Schedule Tasks to get this window

[image]

Double click on "Add Scheduled Task" to get this window

[image]

Click Next

[image]

Click on "Browse" and select the vbs file that we created earlier and click on "open"

The next window that you get is crucial as it is here we need to mention when script needs to run

[image]

After you have done the needful, click on next.

[image]

In this window, enter your login details so that the script can run even when your screen is locked.

Click "Next" when done and then click "Finish" in the next window. Your task scheduler now looks like this

[image]

And you are done

---

Lock your pc and go take a coffee break ;) When you come back (*depending on what time you set in the task scheduler and how much time is your break*), the email would have been sent.

HTH

Comment: Not that I have a problem but you selected my answer in just few seconds :) You should have at least tested it yourself ;)

Comment: +1 Also ensure the the Task Scheduler service is running. (it is on by default, but System Administrators usually turn it off via group policy)

Comment: @Pradeep Kumar : Yup. very true.

Comment: btw, it would help the community if the screen shots for Windows 7 task scheduler will be added? the interface is very different from XP. :p

Comment: @L42: Sure will try and do it later :) Or if you want you can also help me do it :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout as much as i want, can't seem to get to images using the i-stack link. :)

Comment: @mehow: Thanks for taking time to appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

I used HTML and JavaScript setInterval to run vba code to overcome such problem.
Code:

```
<html>
<script>

var flag = false;
var xlApp;
var xlBook;
var i = 0;

function processExcel()
{
//Open the excel containing macro for the first time
if(flag==false)
{
  xlApp = new ActiveXObject ( "Excel.Application" );
//Your Excel containing VBA code
  xlBook=xlApp.Workbooks.Open("Count1.2.xlsm")

}
// "a" is the VBA macro
 xlApp.Run("a");

flag=true;


 i++;
 window.status="Last Updated " + new Date();


}

var w
function run()
{

processExcel();

 w= setInterval("processExcel()",120000);


}
function stop()
{

 clearInterval(w);


}

</script>

<body >

<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="run()" />
<input type="button" value="Stop"  onclick="stop()"/>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

SendKeys is likely the culprit.  I still use CDO to send emails via Excel VBA.  This should get you started:  http://www.rondebruin.nl/cdo.htm