# FindWindows and SendMessgae for Auto-authentication

Tags: excel, vba, authentication, sendmessage, findwindow

I have an Excel automated task that requires an add-in. Use of the add-in requires separate authentication.

There is no way to pass my credentials. I have to manually authenticate when the add-in loads. Because the old-fashioned way launches a new (unauthenticated) instance, I can't figure out how fully automate tasks that require the add-in.

I know that I can use getObject to find the add-in names by using this Add-in Objects within Excel:

```
For i = 1 To AddIns.Count
 Debug.Print (AddIns(i).Name)
 Debug.Print (AddIns(i).FullName)
 Debug.Print (AddIns(i).Title)
 Debug.Print (AddIns(i).Installed)
 Debug.Print (AddIns(i).FullName)
Next
```

This would show the add-in names, in which I can find the add-in by using

```
Set MyObject = AddIns("addin name")
```

or using findWindow(Windows API) to find the add-in instance

```
hWnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Add-in Login Window Title")
```

Reference link on the WindowsAPI getobject and also reference function for Findwindows and SendMessage
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251785(v=office.14).aspx

The addin login windows looks like following:

[image]

I am stuck on how to pass the credentials to this add-in window by referring either thru the object or HWND.

There are some helpful posts: [Open an Excel file in running instance of Excel with Task Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607241/open-an-excel-file-in-running-instance-of-excel-with-task-scheduler/19666151#19666151). and [Open an Excel file in running instance of Excel with Task Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607241/open-an-excel-file-in-running-instance-of-excel-with-task-scheduler)

How can I do authentication thru Windows API, not necessarily thru VBA? I could use Python as well.

Comment: As its a window based app you may use Autoit + VBA. You can record the macro using AutoIt tool and use in VBA.

Comment: Is it your own addin? Then make copy without credentials required. If not, did you ask the programmer/ the software supplier?