# Task Scheduler running but not finishing or working properly VBscript

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I have a vbscript that runs an excel macro. Everything seems right, but it is not working as I had hoped. The task starts but then just continuously running without doing anything.

Let me show you everything I have... I don't get any errors, it just isn't running properly.

**Task scheduler Timeline**

- **Event 110** Task Triggered by user (Task Scheduler launched "{6569c7af-fed8-456b-8c8e-9d1653b8c15a}"  instance of task "\Test"  for user "tsee".
- **Event 319** Task engine received message to start task
- **Event 100** Task started - Task Scheduler started "{6569c7af-fed8-456b-8c8e-9d1653b8c15a}" instance of the "\Test" task for user "METRO\tsee".
- **Event 200** Action Started - Task Scheduler launched action "C:\Users\tsee\Desktop\vbsTest\runTest.vbs" in instance "{6569c7af-fed8-456b-8c8e-9d1653b8c15a}" of task "\Test".
- **Event 129** Created Task Process - Task Scheduler launch task "\Test" , instance "C:\Windows\System32\WScript.exe"  with process ID 8964.

After that it just says *"running"* and doesn't execute anything.

**My VBScript: (runTest.vbs)**

```
Dim xlApp
Dim xlBook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("\\fileserver\homeshares\Tsee\My Documents\Programming\Task Scheduler\runTask.xlsm", 0, True)
xlApp.Run "runTaskTest"
xlBook.Close
xlApp.Quit

Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
```

**My excel Sheet and Macro: (runTask.xlsm)**

```
Sub runTaskTest()
    Dim erow As Long

    erow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Cells(erow + 1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "This test was successful : " & Now

    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Path network: [image]

Comment: 1. verify your network path 2. verify macro name

Comment: @mehow check post... verified... It also says desktop because I moved it actually onto my physical computer to see if that would change anything

Comment: can you add debug points and see when the macro/script is starting to hang?

Comment: @mehow Downloading MSD now. It isn't happening in the excel macro. I have run that without any issues.

Comment: try it like [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388879/vbscript-output-to-console)

Comment: @mehow this is going to sound stupid... but do they mean the cmd prompt? or do I run wscript.exe?

Comment: or add `Application.DisplayAlerts = false` before `ThisWorkbook.Save` - try that too

Comment: @mehow what will the display alerts do?

Comment: Excel may be saying you have made changes to the file do you want to save it? you, for some reason, may not be able to see that message box therefore wouldnt be able to click SAVE and proceed. What the DisplayAlerts does it blocks pop up messages from Excel

Comment: Ok progress!! So... from cmd I did `runTest.vbs` and then got an error that said `Cannot run the macro 'runTaskTest'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.`

Comment: its probably because you do not have all macros enabled by default. you can change that by either enabling all macros by default in Excel(not recommended) or adding a trusted location and placing your xlsm file in there

Comment: @mehow ok, so that is good news. Trying that now

Comment: In Excel -> File -> Options -> Trust Center. Then Trust center settings and trusted locations.

Comment: @mehow didn't work... moved everything to this filepath: `C:\Users\tsee\Desktop\vbsTest` set it up as a trusted location. Fixed all of the path calls and got the same error

Comment: so what if you comment out the `Run` like and execute your vbs

Comment: @mehow so `xlApp "runTaskTest"`? Got no error when I got rid of the whole line

Comment: no temporarily comment out the entire line or remove it and try without it

Comment: @mehow no errors. Do you think I should maybe just change the script to when the file opens run?

Comment: did you tick the box `allow trusted locations on my network` in trust centre in excel?

Comment: also go to Macro settings and `Enable all macros` temporarily

Comment: @mehow ...this is going to sound bad, but I already had that enabled.

Comment: do a ctrl + del + alt and check if you dont have any Excel instances running in the background

Comment: @mehow got rid of all instances of excel and tried again... same error.

Comment: oh thats a shame i think im running out of ideas... where is that excel macro placed? I hope you have added a module and not placed that under a sheet object module? Ie. right click in the VBA Project -> insert -> module

Comment: @mehow Never give up! lol I feel like hitting my head into a wall. The only thing I can think of is the vbscript isn't finding the macro... could it be because its an `xlsm` file or would that have no effect? Would I be able to do a workaround that says when this file is opened by the vbscript execute.

Comment: please just verify that your excel macro is in the right place. It should be in a module and NOT in a Sheet Object Module. See my previous comment

Comment: @mehow well... this is awkward... No more errors... but it isn't printing the data to the sheet like I hoped, so I think its more of just a vba issue now

Comment: @mehow so running the code from the module by itself prints the info to the sheet... but it doesn't do it when run through vbscript... any reason?

Comment: yes because youre opening it read-only probably

Comment: Ive given you the answer it should work, please accept it if youre happy with it :)

Comment: @mehow absolutely! How should I be opening it so that it can be edited?

Comment: when you run the `xlApp.WorkbooksOpen` there are 3 parameters , the third one indicates how to open the workbook - True means ReadOnly which is why the value didn't save in the workbook. Changing it to FALSE means read-write access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to the comments

modify your VBS file

```
Dim xlApp
Dim xlBook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("\\fileserver\homeshares\Tsee\My Documents\Programming\Task Scheduler\runTask.xlsm", 0, False)

xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
xlApp.Visible = False

xlApp.Run "runTaskTest"

xlBook.Saved = True
xlBook.Save

xlBook.Close
xlApp.Quit


Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
```

and your macro

```
Sub runTaskTest()
    Dim erow As Long
    erow = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets(1).Cells(erow + 1, 1).Value = "This test was successful : " & Now

    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

and it should work

Comment: So I am getting an error the says `File in Use` when I try to open the file manually after running the script. I let it run for a minute or so... is something not working properly here?

Comment: the Excel instance might be still hanging in the processes. Reboot your machine run the script and make sure the file is being closed.

Comment: It doesn't seem like the file is being closed. I just went into task manager and cleared out all instances of excel and was able to open it. Any reason for the hang or d you think a reboot is necessary? (fyi as a side note... try out `ctrl + shift + esc` instead of `ctrl + alt + del`)

Comment: many reasons maybe your excel macro throws an error somewhere

Comment: found it... commented out `xlBook.Saved = True` and `xlBook.Save` from the vbs file and it ran perfectly fine. Thanks for all the help. Really, much appreciated.

Comment: next step is getting it to work from the task scheduler... I think it is still hanging in there... running it now, we will see if it manages to complete... but it's already been a minute or two... should be done by now.

Comment: run your macro in excel first and verify that it has no errors etc

Comment: been running it through the cmd prompt. Been working great. Then I try running it from Task Scheduler... its hanging.

Comment: @metsales your original problem should now be solved. Consider asking a new question at this point.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. Truthfully this was the original problem, but at least now we have narrowed down the possibilities.

Comment: It's working now. I think I just had to restart the task scheduler. Cheers!