# Call Outlook procedure using VBScript

Tags: vba, vbscript, outlook

I have a procedure in Outlook that sends all the saved messages in `Drafts` folder.
Below is the code:

```
Public Sub SendMail()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olDraft As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim strfoldername As String
Dim i As Integer

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

strfoldername = olFolder.Parent

Set olDraft = olNS.Folders(strfoldername).Folders("Drafts")

If olDraft.Items.Count <> 0 Then
    For i = olDraft.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        olDraft.Items.Item(i).Send
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

Above code works fine.

**Question:**

I want to use `Task Scheduler` to fire this procedure as a specified time.
1. Where will I put the procedure in Outlook, Module or ThisOutlookSession?
2. I am not good in `vbscript` so I also don't know how to code it to call the Outlook Procedure. I've done calling Excel Procedure but Outlook doesn't support `.Run` property.

So this doesn't work:

```
Dim olApp

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
olApp.Run "ProcedureName"

Set olApp = Nothing
```

I've also read about the `Session.Logon` like this:

```
Dim olApp

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
olApp.Session.Logon
olApp.ProcedureName

Set olApp = Nothing
```

But it throws up error saying object `ProcedureName` is not supported.
Hope somebody can shed some light.

**SOLUTION:**

Ok, I've figured out 2 work around to Avoid or get pass this pop-up.

[image: popup]

**1st one:** is as KazJaw Pointed out.

Assuming you have another program (eg. Excel, VBScript) which includes sending of mail via `Outlook` in the procedure.
Instead of using `.Send`, just `.Save` the mail.
It will be saved in the `Outlook's Draft` folder.
Then using below code,  send the draft which fires using `Outlook Task Reminder`.

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents my_reminder As Outlook.Reminders

Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)

Dim myitem As TaskItem

If Item.Class = olTask Then 'This works the same as the next line but i prefer it since it automatically provides you the different item classes.
'If TypeName(Item) = "TaskItem" Then
    Set my_reminder = Outlook.Reminders
    Set myitem = Item
    If myitem.Subject = "Send Draft" Then
        Call SendMail
    End If
End If

End Sub

Private Sub my_reminder_BeforeReminderShow(Cancel As Boolean)

Cancel = True
Set my_reminder = Nothing

End Sub
```

Above code fires when `Task Reminder` shows with a subject "Send Draft".
But, we don't want it showing since the whole point is just to call the `SendMail` procedure.
So we added a procedure that `Cancels` the display of reminder which is of `olTask` class or `TaskItem` Type.

This requires that `Outlook` is running of course.
You can keep it running 24 hours as i did or, create a `VBscript` that opens it to be scheduled via `Task Scheduler`.

**2nd one:** is to use API to programatically click on <kbd>Allow</kbd> button when the security pop-up appears.
Credits to SiddarthRout for the help.
Here is the [LINK](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/10/23/vbavb-netvb6click-opensavecancel-button-on-ie-download-window/) which will help you programmatically click on the <kbd>Allow</kbd> button.
Of course you have to tweak it a bit.

Comment: I see Sid's answer below and you discussion beneath. Did you consider the following steps of doing the job: **1.** use Window task scheduler to run Outlook (just Outlook.Exe, not VBScript file). I think this would be possible in your OS. **2.** Use `Private Sub Application_Startup() event` in `ThisOutlookSesion`. **3.** In the event set `if statement` referring to time when your macro should start. `Call YourMacro` inside conditional statement. **Conclusion:** If step 1 run at certain time which is checked in step 3, I think, you get what you need.

Comment: @KazJaw thanks for taking the time. But this isn't possible because i have other task scheduled which requires OL to run always. but i'll check if i can set a timing.

Comment: does it mean that you have your OL application (almost) always running? then you could (possibly) use Outlook task to do the job (not Windows System task).

Comment: yes, always running. and yes haven't tried that :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Tried & Tested!**

Assuming that you have Outlook Application always running (according to comment below your question) you can do what you need in the following steps:

1. add a new task in Outlook, set subject to: "run macro YourMacroName" and set time (plus cycles) when your macro should start.
2. go to VBA Editor, open `ThisOutlookSession module` and add the following code inside (plus see the comments inside the code):

   ```
   Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)

   If TypeName(Item) = "TaskItem" Then
       Dim myItem As TaskItem
       Set myItem = Item
       If myItem.Subject = "run macro YourMacroName" Then

           Call YourMacroName    '...your macro name here

       End If
   End If
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Ok this works.:) but how do i dismiss the reminder. If it stays visible, other task won't run. Sorry, haven't deal with task :p also, if i dismiss it, will it still recur based on my settings?

Comment: Ok. Already sorted above comment :D. Thanks for the wonderful idea :D

Answer (score 3):

> Where will I put the procedure in Outlook, Module or ThisOutlookSession?

Neither. Paste the below code in a Text File and save it as a `.VBS` file. Then call this VBS file from the **Task Scheduler** as shown [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211250/excel-vba-email-does-not-send-when-computer-is-locked/10212810#10212810)

```
Dim olApp, olNS, olFolder, olDraft, strfoldername, i

Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(6)

strfoldername = olFolder.Parent

Set olDraft = olNS.Folders(strfoldername).Folders("Drafts")

If olDraft.Items.Count <> 0 Then
    For i = olDraft.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        olDraft.Items.Item(i).Send
    Next
End If
```

Comment: so you're saying that a `call` is not possible?

Comment: No I am not saying that as I have not tested it. One moment. Let me recheck it. The above is a shortest way of doing it.

Comment: ok, i'm doing this because my `Outlook` is having the security pop-up when sending a message was triggered from another program. Out of curiosity, i thought that what if i just call the procedure and `Outlook` still sends the mail, will the pop-up still trigger? Above works, but sending of mail was still triggered by `another` program. so the pop-up still appears.

Comment: I just tested it. You need to place the macto in `ThisOutlookSession`. Once you do that then you can call that macro in outlook using `Application.SendMail`. But this technique seems to be unsupported outside Outlook VBA. Researching more...

Comment: Ok I did a little research and it seems that it doesn't support Application.MyMacro from vbscript.

Comment: yeah, I also came up with the same conclusion. I just did try posting it hoping that somehow, somebody has done the same. I'll leave it here for  a while :D

Comment: Sure. Another link where an outlook MVP says it is possible. See [THIS](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/how-to-run-outlook-macro-from-other-application/7568c68f-51fa-4687-aaee-f5b8103643c7) but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: yep, i've included that in my post. :( that doesn't work. But I'm wondrin why `Application.ProcedureName` works inside `Outlook` while it doesn't in `Excel Vba` or `VBScript`. Didn't the `Set` cover it, passing the `Outlook` application object?

Comment: We can always get rid of the pop up either by reducing the macro security or by using APIs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45443/discussion-between-l42-and-siddharth-rout)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Outlook 2007 or newer I have found you can easily eliminate the security pop up you mentioned above when running your script by doing the following:

1. In Outlook 2007 Trust Center, go to Macro Security - Select "No security Check for macros"
2. In Outlook 2007 Trust Center, go to Programatic Access - Select "Never warn me abous suspicious activity.

Of course that technically leaves you open to the remote possibility for someone to email you some malicious email script or something of that nature I assume.  I trust my company has that managed though and this works for me.  I can use VBS scripts in Outlook, Access, Excel  to send emails with no security pop up.

Another Option:

If you don't want to do that, another option that has worked well for me prior to this is here:
http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/objects.htm

Basically a dll redirect that does not include the popup.  It leaves your other default security in place and you write \ call your VBA for it and send mail without the secutity pop-ups.

Comment: in order to do this, you need to open outlook as administrator!!