# Schedule an email in Outlook 2013 to send at the beginning of every week

Tags: excel, email, outlook

I want to send out an updated excel sheet - that I update on Friday to send - at the beginning of the week (the following Monday).

I'm not sure how I can:

1. Schedule in Outlook to have a recurring email be sent out on Monday at 9 AM
2. Is there a way for my outlook to grab my updated excel from some specified folder on my computer and send it out?

Comment: I'm not sure about Outlook, but you can create an automated task on Windows Task Scheduler to send an email every Monday at 9 AM as you need and you can also specify the path to the attachment, so it'll be updated when the email is sent...

Comment: I can think of two ways. One is already provided by @darkajax but here is a [sample link on how to do it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211250/excel-vba-email-does-not-send-when-computer-is-locked/10212810#10212810) using VBScript. The screen shots are out-dated but I think you can figure it out. Another is using Outlook Reminder to trigger your Email sending code. [Example of such can be found here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21179750/how-to-call-outlook-procedure-using-vbscript-for-use-in-task-scheduler).

Comment: Task Scheduler sounds like it would be easier (???)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to try it with the Task Scheduler, you should do this:

- Open the Task Scheduler
- Select `Create Task`:

[image]

- Go to the `Actions` tab:

[image]

- Select `Send an e-mail`:

[image]

- After configuring your action, go to the `Trigger` tab:

[image]

- Choose `On a schedule` and set the task to run weekly on Mondays as you need:

[image]

Comment: That looks like exactly what I'm looking for!  Just a question though - for the attachment - will it always send out the same attachment on the given weekly basis?

Comment: @StayPuft It'll send the attachment you select as long as it exists (otherwise it'll send an email with no attachment). Also in case you're worried, it's good to point out that the file sent will be on it's current state, so if you updated it'll be the most updated version, not something like the file as it was when you created the task.

Answer (score -1):

The bad thing about this is that you need an SMTP server to work, it cannot be done through Outlook.

Comment: Not exactly, as you can use Outlook's SMTP Server to send email, [see](https://www.lifewire.com/what-are-the-outlook-com-smtp-server-settings-1170671)