# Sending an Outlook email when the Computer is locked

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, scheduled-tasks

I want to send an Outlook email with range from Excel sheet when the Computer is locked

I am running a dashboard which refreshes weekly, using an ODBC connection. I have written a macro which runs on auto_open. The file is opened by Task Scheduler.

System:
Windows 7 SP1,
Outlook 2016,
Excel 2016

Problem: When I schedule the task with the setting as Run whether user is logged on or not, the Excel file opens and gets refreshed, but it does not send the mail, nor does it appear in my outbox. The refresh does happen successfully though. <strike>This is when the user is not logged on.</strike> What I meant was that the computer is locked.

The task schedule works fine when the user is logged on

I have tried this [Excel VBA - Email Does not Send When Computer is Locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211250/excel-vba-email-does-not-send-when-computer-is-locked) and it did not work for me.

The function I am using for sending the mail is:

```
Dim oApp As Object, OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
Dim rng As Range
Dim strbody As String, strtail As String

strbody = "Hi team," & "<br>" & _
         "<a href=""https://example.com"">Here</a> is the link to cloud upload" & Worksheets("Core View").Range("M2") & "<br><br>"
strtail = "Thanks," & "<br>" & _
"Team." & "<br><br>"

On Error Resume Next
'Only the visible cells in the selection
'Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Set rng = Sheets("Core View").Range("A7:K106").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0


If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
      vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
End If

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With


'Create the mail
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = "plaknas@example.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    If EmptySheets <> "" Then
        .Subject = "update has issues in " & EmptySheets
    Else
        .Subject = "Update for week" & Worksheets("Core View").Range("M2")
    End If
    .HTMLBody = strbody & RangetoHTML(rng) & strtail
    .Send   'or use .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0
With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: When no user is logged in, there's no Outlook account to access to send the mail. I'd not expect just anything to be able to grab Outlook and start dumping out emails - would you? That's typically how malware used to behave, which is exactly why Outlook doesn't allow it now.

Comment: @KenWhite I am sorry, but what I meant was that the computer is locked, when I wrote "This is when the user is not logged on." But, what you say makes sense. What surprises me is that it works when the computer is not locked.

Comment: What I said applies to when the user is not logged in, which is what I understood you to mean by *This is when the user is not logged on*. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the Outlook Object Model in a script or program that is run from the Task Scheduler or as a Windows Service.  The security context is quite different and code won't run as intended:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/237913

Comment: Thanks a lot @ericlegault. Have been looking for this exact documentation for days

Comment: You're welcome! I had to hunt for this as well, many links to it were broken, even with a search on the article title