# How to schedule a delivery of mail to a specific time in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

How to schedule a delivery of mail to a specific time in VBA

Code to generate mail

```
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set olItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)
olItem.display
olItem.To = "bhagyashri.kulkarni@mindtree.com"
olItem.Subject = "Auto Generated - Consolidated Task Tracking Report"
olItem.htmlbody = Join(aBody, vbNewLine)
olItem.Attachments.Add outputFileName
olItem.display
```

Will the DeferredDeliveryTime be useful? How to use it ?

Comment: Use VBScript. See [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211250/excel-vba-email-does-not-send-when-computer-is-locked) example

Comment: @SiddharthRout, you don't have to, there's also a mailitem property for this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff869452.aspx user3332507: It's all in there, just read and try for yourself. ;) If you have a specific problem, you are welcome to come back and ask.

Answer (score 7):

I was just too curious, to not answer this question. This piece of code should work.

```
Sub stackfun()  
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set objMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With objMail
 .Display    
 .To = "tomisgreat@something.com"
 .Subject = "you rule"
 'HTML for fun
 .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML     
 .HTMLBody = "<HTML><H2>Y HELO THAR</BODY></HTML>"
 .DeferredDeliveryTime (#11:59:59 PM#)
End With
End Sub
```

Sadly `.DeferredDeliveryTime` only works after Outlook 2013, Siddarth Rout recommended [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211250/excel-vba-email-does-not-send-when-computer-is-locked) VB driven approach in the comments.

Comment: ++ Yeah you are right. For previous versions, one will have to take the route that I mentioned in the comments above.