# Is there a way to auto-update Excel workbook without opening it?

Tags: excel, onedrive, vba

I'm trying to learn better excel skills by working on a hobby project. Currently, my Excel workbook grabs data from an online database and archives it via command button. When I need to, I can look at a summary sheet which analyzes the data and presents it nicely.

The problem is that I need this data to be continuous and if I'm not around to click the command button it will have gaps in the data. The more accurate the better. So, I'm looking for a way that the workbook can be opened, updated and closed without me around. Better yet, if this is possible with something like OneDrive so I don't need my pc on all day - that would be the best solution.

Can anyone suggest a way for this auto-update process to work and/or inform me if OneDrive is capable of doing it also?

Comment: Not sure about OneDrive but you could create a new task in Task Scheduler to run every hour (or whatever granularity you need) that opens the file then closes it. Before starting it, place the code executed by the command button in the Workbook_Open()

Comment: Use the logic described [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211250/excel-vba-email-does-not-send-when-computer-is-locked)